# What is the rationale for using per-method/field access specification?

Tags: java

In C++ the access specifier for a field or method is based on its location under the first previously declared access specification:

```
public:
  int my_public_variable;
private:
  void secretPrivateOperations();
  int internal_counter;
```

What is the design rationale behind Java specifying access by prepending the access specifier to each method/field?

```
public int my_public_variable;
private void secretPrivateOperations();
private int internal_counter;
```

Comment: Actually, the preferred convention in Java `interface`s, which are close to C++ header files, is to omit the access modifier (which defaults to `public`).

Comment: what is the rationale behind C++s way of organizing access specifiers?

Comment: If you change a method's visibility (i. e. from package-private to protected), it is convenient to just that one keyword. Moving around of code make version control less helpful.

Answer (score 3):

To add to **awksp** answer, let's consider a short example. Quite often, you have public API methods implemented with private methods you don't want to expose. You most often want the code of these methods to be close to each other to make the code easier to read, if you don't, here's what it can look like :

```
public:
    void api1() { 
        do_some_stuff();
        private_method();
        some_other_stuff();
    }

   void api2() {
        do_something();
   }

   int api3() {
        int i = a_computation();
        return i + A_CONSTANT;
   }

private:    
   void private_method() {
        do_clever_stuff();
        api1_implementation_details();
   }
```

This is not great to read, `private_method` is far from the only method which uses it, `api1`. This public/private division of the code does not make any logical sense. **You want your code to be organized by its logic, not by the visibility of the methods.**

I very much prefer seeing this :

```
// I can read the whole logic of this method without any clutter
public void api1() { 
   do_some_stuff();
   private_method();
   some_other_stuff();
}

private void private_method() {
   do_clever_stuff();
   api1_implementation_details();
}
// and so on...
```

Answer (score 2):

Compare:

```
public:
    T a();
    T b();
    ...
    T z();
```

versus

```
public:
    T a() {
        <lots of code>
    }
    T b() {
        <lots of code>
    }
protected:
    T c() {
        <more code>
    }
public:
    T d() {
        <more code>
    }
```

If you "factor out" the access specifiers like this, things can get pretty nasty pretty quickly. Yes, indentation helps. Yes, you have Ctrl-F. But there still can be a *lot* of noise to look through (multi-thousand line files, for example), and having to take your mind off of your task just to look for that kind of thing probably wouldn't help productivity.

Java and C++ Java deal with it in different ways. Java keeps access specifiers local, so knowing what method you're working on is enough to determine scope. C++ stuffs declarations together so the access specifier can be "factored out". It may not be as nice when implementing methods, but it's much more concise in header files, and possibly easier to grok too.

Comment: That may be so, but I would like to see the original oracle/java rationale behind this (that is what the question is about).

Comment: Well... I don't think many first-party sources of the Java design process are floating around, so short of James Gosling/someone from Sun answering here I'd imagine most answers would be speculation of some kind or another

Comment: Hmmm. I wonder how much is out there. There's a great rationale entry for not introducing features similar to C++'s "auto" type-deducing keyword.

Comment: Yep, and there are a few great posts by Brian Goetz on design decisions in Java 8's streams/lambdas. I suppose if someone suggested bundled access specifiers as a JSR you'd find better reasoning, but I'm not sure anyone would attempt changing such a fundamental part of the language at this stage

Comment: I guess the bug tracker might be another place to look, but I'd imagine that came around long after this kind of change could be considered

Comment: I'm not really interested in changing the way it is. Merely to understand why it is, as both answers have explained.

Comment: True. I'd imagine that that would be where the best rationale for not implementing that as a possibility would be found, though

Comment: @BourgondAries what's the reason for not introducing auto ? I use Scala and I think the future of statically typed languages is clever type inferrence

Comment: @Dici I saw [this](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4459053). There could be more.

Comment: @awksp Interesting, thanks. To me, the guy was right, and the last syntax is exactly what it would be in Scala or Rust. Anyway, this has nothing to do with the question :)

Comment: That is too much to ask. There was no internet back then... or maybe there was, who knows, it's last century. A lot of communications were not easily accessible as today.